# SwiftUI: Why does ScenePhase behave differently in .onChange()?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, onchange

I recently discovered some behavior of the environment value for Scene Phase in my SwiftUI app that I just cannot explain..

My code basically looks something like this:

```
@Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        // Application code
    }
    .onChange(
        of: scenePhase,
        perform: { newScene in
            setAppActivityStatus(newScene)
            print(newScene)
            print(scenePhase)
        }
    )
}
```

Now, the strange thing is that when using the app on a device/in simulator and putting it in an active/inactive state if find weird print outs in the console:

**Opening app switcher, so app becomes inactive**

first print --> inactive

second print --> active

**Selecting app from app switcher, so app becomes active**

first print --> active

second print --> inactive

Does anyone know how to explain the different results? Thanks!

Comment: The docs say: The system passes the new value into the closure. If you need the old value, capture it in the closure. That's what you are doing isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that was what I thought as well. However, this difference between the two print statements seems to only happen with the ScenePhase ... with other "normal" @ State properties, the same values (always the new ones) get printed to the console.

Comment: I assume that has to do with them triggering a SwiftUI view update on their willSet's not their didSets?